# Jekyll: liquid tag inside javascript

Tags: javascript, jekyll, liquid

Suppose I have two links: "all posts" and "personal." When the user clicks the "personal" link, he should only see the posts that have the category "personal." Right now, the liquid tag is `{% for post in site.posts %}`. I want to learn if there is a way to access the variable `site.posts` from javascript, so that I can listen to the click event and dynamically filter the post. If not, what should I do?

Answer (score 21, accepted):

You can make Jekyll parse any file by adding an empty front matter to it.

**example: assets/js/script.js**

**Edit 16/07/28** : you can use `jsonify` [filter](https://jekyllrb.com/docs/templates/#filters) for any hash or array

```
---
---
{{ site.posts | jsonify }}
```

**Old answer**

```
---
---
{% capture posts %}
[
{% for post in site.posts %}
{
"title"    : "{{ post.title }}",
"url"      : "{{ post.url }}",
"date"     : "{{ post.date | date: "%B %d, %Y" }}",
"content"  : "{{ post.content | escape }}"
} {% if forloop.last %}{% else %},{% endif %}
{% endfor %}
]
{% endcapture %}
var posts = {{posts | strip_newlines}}
```

This will put the `site.posts` objects collection in a `json` form and attribute them to you javascript `posts` var.

Comment: it gives me the error "Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token {" as soon as I include the liquid tags

Comment: Adding the empty front matter to the top of my js file causes the `Liquid Exception: SyntaxError: Unexpected token` warning to trigger.