# How do I include liquid/global variables defined using Jekyll in a Javascript file?

Tags: javascript, variables, jekyll, global, liquid

Currently I'm using Jekyll to build a website, with markdown and html files. If I want to use for example variables defined in the '_data' folder in html/md I can simply use {% for item in site.data.XX %}. My question is, what is the correct syntax when reaching Jekyll variables (e.g. site) in Javascript?

I am using frontmatter in my JS file. Should I include something there or do an import?

I tried:

- console.log(site.collections);
- console.log({{site.collections}});

But I just get the errors "Site is not defined" or "Uncaught SyntaxError: Invalid or unexpected token".

Answer (score 1):

Any file with a front-matter will be processed by jekyll...

eg : **anyfile-with-front-matter.js**

```
---
title: my js file
---
console.log({{page.title}});
console.log({{site.description}});
```

..., except if it is "**ignored**".

By default :

- any underscored folder is ignored (eg: _myfolder)
- node_modules, vendor/bundle/, vendor/cache/, vendor/gems/ and vendor/ruby/ folders are ignored by default configuration

To make contained files available to process, you can add containing folders to include array in your **_config.yml**.

```
include:
 - node_modules
 - _myfolder
```

That's my guess.

Comment: Thanks for answering! My file structure looks like: 

project
    |------ assets
                 |------ js  (where my file is) 
                 |------ other files

In my _config.yml I have not defined any excludes. Can it be ignored anyways? And should I still use the include:

Answer (score 1):

I just found the problem (you solved it previously David): 
[Jekyll: liquid tag inside javascript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28142507/jekyll-liquid-tag-inside-javascript)

It seems like it prints out correctly (without syntax errors) when adding:

console.log({{ site.collections | jsonify }})

Answer (score 1):

Jekyll is a static-site-generator that essentially *runs just once*. The only time it runs continuously is when you invoke either of the following commands: `jekyll serve` or `jekyll build --watch`.

On the other hand, JavaScript scripts are meant to be run on each request for a given page. Unless there's a server running with Jekyll, your scripts won't be able to *use* the so-called global variables.

However, that said, you can still use Jekyll variables to *generate* a static JS script.
For example, consider the following contents:

#### `./_data/navigation.yml`

```
- label: Home
  url: "/"
- label: About Us
  url: "/about/"
```

#### `./_includes/script-template.html`

```
<script>
  {% for entry in site.data.navigation %}
    console.log('{{ entry.label }}');
  {% endfor %}
</script>
```

#### `./test.html`

```
---
---
<body>
  {% include script-template.html %}
</body>
```

If you were to build the site containing above files, the generated html file `./_site/test.html` will look like the following:

```
<body>
  <script>

    console.log('Home');
    console.log('About Us');

  </script>
</body>
```